# LIKE with % and bindValue for a MySQL PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pretty sure this is a question already answered. I am reading a lot of posts but I cannot understand.
I am trying to retrieve from the database all the articles which contain 'art' in the title  (for example).
I have the following function in my class:

```
public function searchArtTitle($art_title_search)
{
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
$query_art_title = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE art_title LIKE :$artt');
$query_art_title->bindValue(':artt', '%$art_title_search%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_art_title->execute();
else {
        echo "DB article title search failed";
    return false; }
}
```

Here is the code which uses the class:

```
<?php
require_once("../config/config.php");
require_once("get_art.php");

$articles = new get_art();

$search_word = 'Art';
$search_res=$articles->searchArtTitle($search_word);
print_r($search_res2);
foreach($search_res as $search_item) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo $search_item['art_title'] . "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

I get an empty array, which shouldn't.
I guess there are multiple errors here...please help a stupid newbie :D

Comment: [Single quotes mean literal string.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: so?
are you saying that '%$art_title_search%' doesn't work?
should I write
'%' . $art_title_search . '%'
?

Comment: Yes. Also please click the link to the manual I provided.

Comment: I tried '%' . $art_title_search . '%' but without results.
Of course I clicked the link you provided but I didn't find anything which helps me...maybe I don't even know what I should look for. Can you please point the part I should be interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be

```
$query_art_title = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE art_title LIKE :artt');
```

? without the `$` on `:artt`

EDIT: oh I see you already found that

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was editing everything trying to find the error and I ended inserting another error...LOL!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function searchArtTitle($art_title_search)
{
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
$query_art_title = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE art_title LIKE :$artt'); **// <- REMOVE THE DOLLAR**
$keyword = "%".$art_title_search."%";
$query_art_title->bindValue(':artt', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_art_title->execute();
else {
        echo "DB article title search failed";
    return false; }
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! I have a $ in the prepare statement...that was the error...thanks anyways for the quick answers!!!